# Foco en textBox antes de escanear código de barras

Tags: c#, eventos, onkeypress

Estoy haciendo un formulario de entrada de artículos, este tiene un grid y un textBox de entrada.

Necesito cerciorarme que cuando se escanee un artículo, el foco esté en el textBox, hacer la entrada y esperar el 'enter' para procesar el código.
Esto lo he probado con el evento `KeyDown` del formulario:

```
private void frmMainSeries_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

    this.ActiveControl = txtSerie;
    txtSerie.Focus();
}
```

Pero de esta forma, si estoy fuera del textBox, la primera tecla no la escribe.
Hace el `focus()` correctamente, pero la tecla que provoca eso no se inserta en el `textBox`.

¿Me podéis echar un cable por favor? Muchas gracias.

Comment: bueno.. la tecla te vino en e, no? probaste agregarla a mano...

Comment: Ya lo he probado, pero la tecla '1' por ejemplo me viene como 'D1' por ello creía que algo no hacía bien.

Comment: no te viene el char de la tecla?

Comment: string ch = ((Char)e.KeyCode).ToString(); Así si, perdón.

Comment: Entonces? ya se soluciono?

Comment: Bueno, digamos que el problema ahora es otro, ahora me duplica los carácteres, el que le doy yo y a partir del segundo el resto, si condiciono el añadir el caracter manualmente al hecho de que el control no tenga el foco, lo que hace es concatenarme el resto a la izquierda del primero.

Comment: e tiene una propiedad para cancelar que siga procesando ;)... estarias haciendo todo manual pero funcionaria... si no.. una bandera que diga cual es el primero...